Loop at Xorg login only to start with Wayland
VM VirtualBoxst is the same for both
Version 7.0.18 r162988 (Qt5.15.3)
VBox_GAs_7.0.18
This works 22.04:
ubuntu-22-04@ubuntu2204-VirtualBox:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
ubuntu-22-04@ubuntu2204-VirtualBox:~$

ubuntu-22-04@ubuntu2204-VirtualBox:~$ uname -r
6.5.0-35-generic
ubuntu-22-04@ubuntu2204-VirtualBox:~$
This is the only thing that works with 24.04:
ubuntu-24-04-1@ubuntu-24-04-VirtualBox:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
ubuntu-24-04-1@ubuntu-24-04-VirtualBox:~$

No x11
the log report has been generated by first starting with wayland - logged in
finished
now started with Xorg
login does not work
login again with wayland
the log has been created
    ubuntu-24-04-1@ubuntu-24-04-1-VirtualBox:~$ cat .local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log| grep -i "(ee)"
 (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 67.737] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[ 69.629] (EE)
[ 69.629] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 69.637] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x14c) [0x6116e12c0dbc]
[ 69.637] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x72e0ae845320]
[ 69.637] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (pthread_kill+0x11c) [0x72e0ae89eb1c]
[ 69.637] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0x1e) [0x72e0ae84526e]
[ 69.637] (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0xdf) [0x72e0ae8288ff]
[ 69.637] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[ 69.637] (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (?+0x0) [0x72e0ae82881b]
[ 69.637] (EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__assert_fail+0x47) [0x72e0ae83b507]
[ 69.637] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRIMoveBuffersHelper+0xbd3) [0x6116e12773c3]
[ 69.637] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2Authenticate+0xa6) [0x6116e12796a6]
[ 69.637] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2GetParam+0x6b9) [0x6116e127a409]
[ 69.637] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x3e4) [0x6116e1141ab4]
[ 69.637] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3b2) [0x6116e1145e52]
[ 69.637] (EE) 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_init_first+0x8a) [0x72e0ae82a1ca]
[ 69.637] (EE) 13: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x8b) [0x72e0ae82a28b]
[ 69.637] (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x25) [0x6116e112e395]
[ 69.637] (EE)
[ 69.637] (EE)
[ 69.637] (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
[ 69.637] (EE)
[ 69.637] (EE)
[ 69.637] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/ubuntu-24-04-1/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 69.637] (EE)
[ 69.643] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
ubuntu-24-04-1@ubuntu-24-04-1-VirtualBox:~$

I use a translation machine and try to use simple words

It's more of a coincidence or luck. I have read on the net that the 3D option should be switched off. My play instinct: this is the only option I have not yet tried in the VM. It was always off. Just set it to on. A 100% hit. More luck than skill.
both works
ubuntu-24-04-1
Memory size:                 8009MB
VRAM size:                   102MB
Graphics Controller:         VMSVGA
Monitor count:               1
3D Acceleration:             enabled

ubuntu-22-04
Memory size:                 8192MB
VRAM size:                   32MB
Graphics Controller:         VMSVGA
3D Acceleration:             disabled


What's this "luck/skill" talk, I don't understand. Confirmed: enabling "3D acceleration" in VBox VM settings fixes the issue with Xorg "Caught signal 6 (Aborted)" on a clean 24.04.1 install.
